# why am i getting error after importing bootsrap-dark-5 in react file?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap-dark-5/dist/css/bootsrap-dark-5.min.css';

//error
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 8:0-75

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap-dark-5/dist/css/bootsrap-dark-5.min.css' in 'C:\Users\ankan\Desktop\food app\zebrakat\khana\src'


// my error 
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 8:0-75

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/bootstrap-dark-5/dist/css/bootsrap-dark-5.min.css' in 'C:\Users\ankan\Desktop\food app\zebrakat\khana\src'
```

Answer (score 0):

install bootstrap-dark-5 with the command in terminal:

npm i bootstrap-dark-5